# Determine if users are friends to one another from twitter user ids using rtweet/igraph

Tags: r, twitter, igraph, rtweet

I am using twitter data for machine learning and while trying to find relations between users i got stuck at lookup_friendships from the rtweet package in R.
Actually i have a list of user IDs like:-

```
frnd_20$user_id
<chr>
818910970567344128              
52544275                
39344374                
41634520                
22203756                
39349894                
50769180                
22703645                
471672239               
23970102
```

is there any way to determine whether any of the above users is friends to each other. I tried using get_friendships() but it gave a dataframe of around 2000 rows and looking through them to find friendship is quite time consuming.

```
    df <- c()
for ( i in 1:20) {
  source_frnd <- frnd_20$screen_name[i]
  for(j in 1:20){
    target_frnd <- frnd_20$screen_name[j]
    a<-lookup_friendships(source_frnd,target_frnd)
    df <- rbind(df,a)
  }

}
```

is there any other way to determine how many users are friends to each other. Would be really great if you reply.
Thanks in advance
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer looks at your current data set and checks if there are any relations among the users and who they follow (friendships in `rtweet` package terminology). None are found. You might want to check it with some users you know are related.

```
# reading in the data provided
a <- "
818910970567344128              
52544275                
39344374                
41634520                
22203756                
39349894                
50769180                
22703645                
471672239               
23970102 "

df <- read.table(text = a, header = FALSE)
names(df) <- "targ_users"
df$targ_users <- as.character(df$targ_users)

# getting followed accounts with the rtweet function `get_friends`
frnds <- get_friends(users = df$targ_users)

library(dplyr)
frnds %>% group_by(user) %>% summarise(n = n())
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   user                   n
   <chr>              <int>
 1 22203756              40
 2 22703645              97
 3 23970102              76
 4 39344374            1463
 5 39349894             926
 6 41634520               4
 7 471672239            832
 8 50769180             343
 9 52544275            1448
10 818910970567344128    15

frnds %>% group_by(user) %>% filter(user %in% user_id)
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# Groups:   user [0]
# ... with 2 variables: user <chr>, user_id <chr>
```

If the coding is correct, then this indicates none of the users (`user`) are following the other users. I checked this a different way below...

```
# make data frame of just the users
u_df <- as.data.frame(unique(frnds$user)) 

# make data frame of all the followed users
f_df <- as.data.frame(unique(frnds$user_id))

# check if any common id's are in the two groups
u_df %in% f_df
[1] FALSE
```

This confirms the original answer - no users in the set follow the other users.